# How to hide savefiledialog box c#

Tags: c#, .net, savefiledialog

I want to save my pictures in silent. I mean without showing the save file box
here is save picture code.

```
string path = textBox1.Text.ToString();
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "jpg|*.jpg";
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = path;
saveFileDialog1.AddExtension = false;
saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;
saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = false;
saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".jpg";
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
{
  if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    Uri realLink = new Uri(link);
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(realLink, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
  }
}));
```

Comment: How do you know where you want to save the files?

Comment: Then don't use it?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't get the question...why do you _show_ a save file dialog if you don't want to?

Comment: Hide it by not creating it in the first place. DownloadFileAsync just needs a file name not a class member of SaveFileDialog.

Comment: @RossBush by giving path in a textbox

Answer (score 2):

From the code you posted it seems you already know the path and file name. So you can simply:

```
string destination = Path.Combine(textBox1.Text.ToString(), fileName);
Uri realLink = new Uri(link);
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFileAsync(realLink, destination);
```

Comment: nothing saved on my path